# For two columns, how to sum the values in 1st column grouped by 2nd column?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have the following flat file and would like to determine the sum of all points in the first column for each user.  For example:

```
50       user1
100      user2
10       user1
20       user3
```

Would return

```
60       user1
100      user2
20       user3
```

Is it possible to do this bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
#!awk -f
{
  foo[$2] += $1
}    
END {
  for (bar in foo)
    print foo[bar], bar
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{a[$2]+=$1}END{for(i in a )print a[i],i}' your_file
```